# Is there any published version of The Sorcerer's/Philosopher's Stone which have a solvable potions puzzle?

Tags: harry-potter, revision

I remember as a child, I read the Sorcerer's Stone and tried to figure out the riddle. It read as follows:

> First, however slyly the poison tries to hide
>
> You will always find some on nettle wine’s left side;
>
> Second, different are those who stand at either end,
>
> But if you would move onwards, neither is your friend;
>
> **Third, as you see clearly, all are different size,**
>
> **Neither dwarf nor giant holds death in their insides;**
>
> Fourth, the second left and the second on the right
>
> Are twins once you taste them, though different at first sight.

Unfortunately, these lines weren't enough to solve the puzzle, particularly due to the bolded line and the fact that the bottle sizes weren't described from right to left.

Was this ever changed or an illustration given that would make it solvable for the reader?

Comment: Ahem; http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/The_Potion_Puzzle

Comment: @Valorum - Significantly higher resolution image [here](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/ytYWw9Eota22KOi42WwoQ/2405f106e75833b80276ffe5cb629a2d/PotionsClassroom_PM_B1C16M3_PotionsLinedUpForPhilosophersStoneCharm_Moment.jpg).

Comment: [Related on Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/24955/48193), notably with [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/94132/48193) expanding on how to resolve the thing without a picture of the set of potions (as the reader is not given a picture in the book).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As shown in the essay ["The riddle of the potions"](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/2004/05/02/the-riddle-of-the-potions/) by  Mark B. Hammer, there are only two possible setups of the seven bottles given the textual clues in the book.

> 1. Poison | Wine | Poison | Forward | Poison | Wine | Back
> 2. Poison | Wine | Forward | Poison | Poison | Wine | Back

The text of the book has never been changed to specify which one is correct, and none of the print editions have any illustrations of the scene.

[The only officially licensed illustration of the scene](https://images.pottermore.com/bxd3o8b291gf/ytYWw9Eota22KOi42WwoQ/2405f106e75833b80276ffe5cb629a2d/PotionsClassroom_PM_B1C16M3_PotionsLinedUpForPhilosophersStoneCharm_Moment.jpg) that I am aware of (drawn by Charlie Bowater of Atomhawk Design ltd for Pottermore's old website) goes with the second possibility.

[image]

The illustration is included in the "Enhanced Edition" of *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, available exclusively from the iBooks store.

Of course like all official artwork, J.K. Rowling wasn't involved in its creation, so your opinion on its canonicity may vary.

Comment: When you say that "most editions do not have any illustrations of the scene", are you aware of any that do?

Comment: @PaulOmans - Just the Enhanced Edition iBook. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: I just stepped through the possibilities and got down to those two as well.

Comment: there is a newly released illustrated edition as well  - wonder if it is in there? https://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Sorcerers-Stone-Illustrated/dp/0545790352

Comment: @NKCampbell - I checked before posting my answer. It isn't.

Comment: There is a video in french that explains that...
With just the clues in the book it is impossible to know the exact sequence of potions, but because Hermione manage to find the good one, there is only one sequence that may let her know with absolute certitude...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wl6Re86QZxs